# Separate UI and API server

Tags: jhipster

I am new to Jhipster application. I have successfully developed application by using Jhipster.
Now i want to deploy application in Tomcat server. So i am trying to generate war by using mvnw -Pdev package command. its successfully generated war.
Now i am trying to deploy this war into tomcat, its successfully deployed. But i am facing issue as its running only backend(API) server only.
I am unable to run frontend application in browser.
could you please any one help me on this. I want to run UI and API server in tomcat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

-Pdev is for development it was not made for deploying into Tomcat, in dev you are supposed to run frontend code from webpack dev server not from java backend because you want to benefit from frontend code hot reloading.

If you still want to run in Tomcat for dev without hot reloading (bad for your productivity), run a -Pprod build so that your war includes the javascript bundle of your frontend code

As a general comment, deploying a JHipster app into any app server usually requires more effort than embracing the executable jar recommended approach.